# How to add to SortedSet items from an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, treeset, sortedset

I have a SortedSet defined this way:

```
SortedSet<RatedMessage> messageCollection = new TreeSet<RatedMessage>(new Comp());
```

and I have an array of RatedMessage[]

I had to use the array as the set misses the serialization feature, now I need to construct it back.

Is there a quick way to add all the items from the array to the set again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Collections.addAll(messageCollection, array);
```

Functionally identical to Michael's answer, but as the javadoc says:

> Adds all of the specified elements to
>   the specified collection. Elements to
>   be added may be specified individually
>   or as an array. The behavior of this
>   convenience method is identical to
>   that
>   c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements)),
>   but this method is likely to run
>   significantly faster under most
>   implementations.

Comment: Oh, well done. "The behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements)), but this method is likely to run significantly faster under most implementations."

Comment: Just as I was adding that same quote. =)

Answer (score 5):

`Set` has an [`addAll`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) method, but it only takes a collection, so you'll need to convert the array first:

```
RatedMessage[] arr;
messageCollection.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add **RatedMessage[]** array into **SortedSet** using **Arrays.asList** with **TreeSet**

```
String RatedMessage[]={"1","2","3","1","4","3"};
SortedSet lst= new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(RatedMessage));
Iterator it = lst.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Object ob= it.next();
            System.out.println(ob);
        }
```